# Custom ReferenceID property for buttons and menu classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

For ASP controls - let us say we are using button, is it possible to derive from BUTTON, a derived control and create new property called, say , ReferenceID (type say integer) and use that property.

I would like to have a unique id for the control other than the ID we are having

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible and the way you are thinking about it will work but keep in mind that you will have to keep track of the values assigned to this property in ViewState. What I mean is this (untested code):

```
public class CustomButtom : Button
{

     public int ReferenceID {  
       get {
              if(ViewState["ReferenceID"]!=null)
                return int.Parse(ViewState["ReferenceID"].ToString());
              return -1;
           }
      set  {
             ViewState["ReferenceID"]=value;
           } 

     } 
}
```

Comment: I didn't get this clearly can you tell how can i use this as per my requirement

Comment: create an object for custom button and add as following `CustomButtom c = new CustomButtom();
        c.ReferenceID = 1;`

Comment: Ok how can i apply this value for my own button or some control so that it doesn't apply to another control in the form